# Why do browsers download the image when you hit save, rather than copying it from cache?

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, internet, browser, download

This is true for almost all browsers. If a large image (.jpg) has been fully loaded and displayed it means the file has already been downloaded on to user's computer, right? So saving it should be a matter of copying from cache over to the desired location. Instead the download starts all the way from 0. I tested this on Chrome, Firefox and IE 10.

note : most browsers have a context menu option to save image, which is what I am talking about.

Comment: What happens if you just drag the image to the desktop instead?

Comment: @Tetsujin I don't know.

Comment: @Tetsujin - Won't this copy the image as rendered for display in the browser, rather than the original image, which may have a different resolution?

Comment: How do you know it is downloading again in FF? When I checked network activity in Developer Tools, either saving from the context menu (save as ...) or from the Page Info media tab did not result in an additional download. Page Info should show the true image size.